# Flex grow and Flex fill or shrink not working when the next flex element has long text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I would like for the `color-swatch` to fill the space it has been set at in the CSS (`width: 40px`) and for the swatch label to shrink. But the problem is: if the label is a long word like "Corn flower blue", the color-swatch shrinks in size not keeping its width.

The HTML below uses Bootstrap 4 classes. I have tried to add `flex-fill` and `flex-grow-1` to the `color-swatch` and flex-shrink-1 to the `swatch label` but none of these combinations work
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink

Here is a working example in Codepen
https://codepen.io/ben_jammin/pen/Vwadqqb

```css
.container {
  background-color:red;
}
.sidebar {
  width:280px;
  padding:1.5rem;
  background-color:#efefef;
}
li {list-style-type: none;}
.color-swatch {width:40px; height:40px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="sidebar">
<ul class="swatches d-flex flex-wrap m-0 pl-0" role="menu">
    <li class="swatch mb-2 col-6 px-0">
        <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
      <!-- Swatch -->
         <span class="color-swatch d-flex flex-grow-1" style="background-color:black;"></span> 
      <!-- Swatch Label -->
         <span class="stacked label ml-2 d-flex">Black</span></a>
    </li>
  <li class="swatch mb-2 col-6 px-0">
        <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
      <!-- Swatch -->
         <span class="color-swatch d-flex flex-grow-1" style="background-color:blue;"></span> 
      <!-- Swatch Label -->
         <span class="stacked label d-flex ml-2">Blue</span></a>
    </li>
  <li class="swatch mb-2 col-6 px-0">
        <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
      <!-- Swatch -->
         <span class="color-swatch d-flex flex-grow-1" style="background-color:cornflowerblue;"></span> 
      <!-- Swatch Label -->
         <span class="stacked label d-flex ml-2">Corn flower blue</span></a>
    </li>
  <li class="swatch mb-2 col-6 px-0">
        <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
      <!-- Swatch -->
         <span class="color-swatch d-flex flex-grow-1" style="background-color:forestgreen;"></span> 
      <!-- Swatch Label -->
         <span class="stacked label d-flex ml-2">Forest green</span></a>
    </li>
  <li class="swatch mb-2 col-6 px-0">
    <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
      <!-- Swatch -->
     <span class="color-swatch d-flex flex-grow-1" style="background-color:gray;"></span> 
      <!-- Swatch Label -->
     <span class="stacked label d-flex ml-2">Gray</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="swatch mb-2 col-6 px-0">
    <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
      <!-- Swatch -->
     <span class="color-swatch d-flex flex-grow-1" style="background-color:darkblue;"></span> 
      <!-- Swatch Label -->
     <span class="stacked label d-flex ml-2">Midnight Blue</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap classes `d-flex` and `flex-grow-1` on your swatches are overriding your css styling.

Try removing those and adjusting the sizes of your swatches and labels how you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, Alan. Not sure the question is clear enough. The color swatch size is dynamic so I need it to always be the width & height that is set, and allow the swatch label to shrink to make room for the color swatch. Can you explain how those classes are overriding my CSS?

Comment: Sounds like you want your swatch to stay the same size (which is what removing those classes will do) but you need a responsive font style that'll adjust to the view size. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_text.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are just using the wrong combination of flex classes.

Adding `flex-grow-1` to the color-swatch and `flex-shrink-1` to the label tells the swatch to *use all the available space it can*, and the label to *shrink if it can*. This isn't exactly the behaviour you want... What you really want to do is tell the color-swatch *not to shrink*.

You can do this using the `flex-shrink-0` class. Adding this to all your `color-swatch` elements will keep them at 40x40px and let the label use whatever space is left. You also don't need the `d-flex` on either color-swatch or label:

```
<a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
    <!-- Swatch -->
     <span class="color-swatch flex-shrink-0" style="background-color:black;"></span>
     <!-- Swatch Label -->
     <span class="stacked label ml-2">Black</span>
</a>
```

You might also want to add `align-items-center` to your `ul` element also -"cornflower blue" wraps to 2 lines so this will vertically centre "Forest Green".

**Working Example:**

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 280px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.color-swatch {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="swatches d-flex flex-wrap m-0 pl-0 align-items-center" role="menu">
      <li class="swatch mb-2 col-6 px-0">
        <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
          <!-- Swatch -->
          <span class="color-swatch flex-shrink-0" style="background-color:black;"></span>
          <!-- Swatch Label -->
          <span class="stacked label ml-2">Black</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="swatch mb-2 col-6 px-0">
        <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
          <!-- Swatch -->
          <span class="color-swatch flex-shrink-0" style="background-color:blue;"></span>
          <!-- Swatch Label -->
          <span class="stacked label ml-2">Blue</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="swatch mb-2 col-6 px-0">
        <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
          <!-- Swatch -->
          <span class="color-swatch flex-shrink-0" style="background-color:cornflowerblue;"></span>
          <!-- Swatch Label -->
          <span class="stacked label ml-2">Corn flower blue</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="swatch mb-2 col-6 px-0">
        <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
          <!-- Swatch -->
          <span class="color-swatch flex-shrink-0" style="background-color:forestgreen;"></span>
          <!-- Swatch Label -->
          <span class="stacked label ml-2">Forest green</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="swatch mb-2 col-6 px-0">
        <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
          <!-- Swatch -->
          <span class="color-swatch flex-shrink-0" style="background-color:gray;"></span>
          <!-- Swatch Label -->
          <span class="stacked label ml-2">Gray</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="swatch mb-2 col-6 px-0">
        <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
          <!-- Swatch -->
          <span class="color-swatch flex-shrink-0" style="background-color:darkblue;"></span>
          <!-- Swatch Label -->
          <span class="stacked label ml-2">Midnight Blue</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```